# npm install and fails on node-gyp rebuild with ```gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!``` caused by new macos catalina update

Tags: node.js, xcode, npm-install, macos-catalina, node-gyp

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:344:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/bin/node" "/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/synapse/Documents/synapsefi-dev-ui/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN synapsefi-dev-ui@2.0.20 No repository field.
npm WARN The package country-data is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react-dropzone is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 in

```html
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:344:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:213:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/bin/node" "/Users/synapse/.nvm/versions/node/v8.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/synapse/Documents/synapsefi-dev-ui/node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v8.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN synapsefi-dev-ui@2.0.20 No repository field.
npm WARN The package country-data is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN The package react-dropzone is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules/watchpack/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
```

stall: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

Comment: Issue persists with macOS Big Sur :-(
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68545087/macos-big-sur-when-i-run-npm-install-i-get-an-error-during-the-step-node-gy/68545088#68545088

Answer (score 1):

The repository `node-gyp` contains a dedicated troubleshooting guide for macOS Catalina:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md

TLDR:

> **Installation notes for macOS Catalina (v10.15)**
>
> Both upgrading to macOS Catalina and running a Software Update in
> Catalina may cause normal node-gyp installations to fail. This might
> manifest as the following error during npm install:
>
> `gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`
>
> **Solutions**
>
> There are three ways to install the Xcode libraries `node-gyp` needs on
> macOS. People running Catalina have had success with some but not
> others in a way that has been unpredictable.
>
> - With the full Xcode (~7.6 GB download) from the App Store app.
> - With the much smaller Xcode Command Line Tools via `xcode-select --install`
> - With the much smaller Xcode Command Line Tools via manual download.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your finder and type in "Terminal" to open the Terminal app.
Copy and paste: sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
push enter
*you have now manually removed your command line tools

then go to https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ and search "Command Line Tools for Xcode 11.3.1"
Click it and then download it
*you have now manually added a command line tools set

**Note: My Macbook Pro then kept telling me to update my command lines software. I ended up updating my software to Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.2 and it still works. I would recommend trying to update your Command Line Tools if your computer settings says it's available. If not, do the steps I just mentioned and it should work :slight_smile:

Answer (score 0):

try running the command `npm config set sass_binary_site=https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/node-sass`, My problem was fixed by changing the source of node-sass.