# macOS Big Sur: When I run `npm install`, I get an error during the step `node-gyp rebuild`: `gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`

Tags: node.js, npm-install, macos-big-sur, node-gyp, xcode-command-line-tools

On macOS Big Sur,
with node v14.17.1,
when I run `npm install` (for the package `jq`)
then I get the error (during the installation of the dependent node_module `contextify`):

```
node-gyp rebuild

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'. 

gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
```

Note that I already installed the Xcode command-line tools. `xcode-select --install` displays:

> xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

and no possible update appears in "Software Update".

Note: Unsure if that's related, but my Mac had an OS update earlier today...

Comment: Similar question for macOS Catalina: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64615425/npm-install-and-fails-on-node-gyp-rebuild-with-gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-d

Answer (score 0):

The repository `node-gyp` contains a dedicated troubleshooting guide for macOS Catalina:

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md

Apparently, it still applies also for macOS Big Sur

TLDR:

> **Installation notes for macOS Catalina (v10.15)**
>
> Both upgrading to macOS Catalina and running a Software Update in
> Catalina may cause normal `node-gyp` installations to fail. This might
> manifest as the following error during `npm install`:
>
> `gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!`
>
> **Solutions**
>
> There are three ways to install the Xcode libraries `node-gyp` needs on
> macOS. People running Catalina have had success with some but not
> others in a way that has been unpredictable.
>
> - With the full Xcode (~7.6 GB download) from the App Store app.
> - With the much smaller Xcode Command Line Tools via `xcode-select --install`
> - With the much smaller Xcode Command Line Tools via manual download.

---

This "solved" it for me:

Download the current *Command Line Tools for Xcode* from the Apple Developer webpage:
https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=command

(Currently: Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.5.1, installer size 483 MB, requires 2.7 GB disk space)

Though I get further build errors during `node-gyp rebuild` now... (for the package contextify) - but that's something that probably should be addressed separately.